# Have error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection when do lapply

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a folder with about 100 file txt. I only run simpl code:

```r
> setwd("E:/Yunlin/SMUNPO/TXTFILE/")
> filenames <- list.files(getwd(),pattern="*.txt")
> textfiles <- lapply(filenames, readLines)
```

However, the result is `Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection`. I tried to set the working directory, change the file name to be simple, but none of it works. I test with readLines function for a specific file name. It works. But not for all the folder. Anyone can help, thank you in advanced?

Answer (score 0):

- You *must* use regex-style patterns in `pattern`, not glob-style.

  From [`?list.files`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html):

  ```r
   pattern: an optional regular expression.  Only file names which match
            the regular expression will be returned.
  ```

  So it is expecting regex, not glob-style patterns.

  Use one of these options:

  ```r
  list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")
  list.files(pattern = utils::glob2rx("*.txt"))
  ```

  (To learn regex, I suggest both https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 and https://www.regular-expressions.info/. Note that backslashes in regular expressions usually need to be double-blackslashes; for example, `\b` (word boundary) in R needs to be `\\b`.)
- You *should* use `full.names=TRUE`, precluding the need for the `setwd`/`getwd` dance. I suggest something like:

  ```r
  # no need for `setwd`
  filenames <- list.files("E:/Yunlin/SMUNPO/TXTFILE/", pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE)
  ```